# Update user mailbox settings

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to [update `mailboxSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update-mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) using the Microsoft Graph .NET SDKbut I cannot find a way that works.

This is my current code:

```cs
var client = new GraphServiceClient(clientCredentialProvider);
Guid userId;
var user = new User {
    MailboxSettings = new MailboxSettings
    {
        AutomaticRepliesSetting = new AutomaticRepliesSetting()
        {
            InternalReplyMessage = "test reply...",
            ExternalReplyMessage = "test reply...",
            ExternalAudience = ExternalAudienceScope.All,
            Status = AutomaticRepliesStatus.AlwaysEnabled,
        },
    },
};
var result = await ApplicationClient.Users[userId].Request().UpdateAsync(user);
```

This is the exception:

```
Code: ErrorInvalidRequest
Message: The OData request is not supported.
```

PS: This is my first post on SO, so I would be happy about suggestions on how to improve the post.